# UIMediaPickerController under iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios8, mpmediapickercontroller

I've run into an issue with the media picker on iOS 8.
I have an iPad application, landscape mode supported only.
The following code works just fine under iOS 6 and iOS 7, but on iOS 8, it presents the media picker in landscape mode, but a vertical gradient line appears along the right side of the picker, where the portrait version would have its right edge. The picker works fine also to the right of this line, but I cannot figure out, how to make this gradient go away.

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];

    [self presentViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}
```

I'd appreciate your expert help ;

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was changing the Orientation in the Deployment info. I had to uncheck the "Landscape" box. Of course now the orientation is not fixed but at least the "black gradient" problem was solved.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, however, this is not an option for me, landscape mode needs to be fixed in my app at all times.